# DataGridView, always keep first column visible whilst horizontally-scrolling?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 10 columns, lets say columns 7, 8, 9 and 10 are hidden when column 0 is visible as the form is a little narrow. I can scroll horizontally to view column 10, but this hides column0.

How can I keep column0 visible at all times whilst scrolling horizontally? So the scrollbar wouldn't actually extend to column0.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (so I think thats .net 5?)

Comment: @LarsTech havent tried it yet but if you post this as an answer I can accept it if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [Frozen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.frozen(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether a column will move when a user scrolls the DataGridView control horizontally.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
```